# Wyse Enhanced Ubuntu Terminal Locked Down?

Tags: cron, terminal, wyse

I'm dealing with about 20 Wyse T50 thin-clients and I want to set up cron, however, it seems like there are a number of things locked down in the Wyse Enhanced Ubuntu terminal.

For instance, 'crontab -e' and 'sudo crontab -e' both open empty crontab files (creating them because they didn't exist before). Normal file behavior I know, but it surprised me to see no existing cron configuration for sudo users.

Also, 'sudo shutdown now' exits the GUI and goes into full terminal mode, but doesn't actually shut down. Instead it lists out some random configuration stats and prompts me for credentials to log back in.

I'm a CentOS user, so perhaps I'm just experiencing what is normal Ubuntu behavior, but I'd like to know if anyone has experience with Wyse Enhanced Ubuntu and how to control via cron and via terminal commands as you would a normal Linux core.

All I can find on the web are marketing materials and really basic GUI setup tuts.

Comment: Are you trying to run Ubuntu or a thin term?

Comment: Hey, sorry, just saw this. It's running Ubuntu.